# Electron as a wave function, is it a wave bubble?

Tags: waves, electrons, bubbles

Something I have been pondering.

We tend to think of a physical particle as a grain of sand or at atomic levels maybe an electron(lepton).

If I now choose to consider an electron as a wave, typically we think of  a photon as a wave packet, apply that thought to an electron. We may choose to contemplate an electron wave packet as appearing with unpredictable spontaneity anywhere within an appropriate energy shell . I feel a bit uncomfortable with this idea as it implies that it exists at one place disappears to exist at another with some random statistics, that have polarity affecting probability of local appearance.

We think of a wave packet moving/rotating in 3 dimensions through space time. What if we extended the idea of an electron as an “oscillating wave bubble” energy field that exists everywhere in its orbital shell. Maybe an incoming particle or photon might collide when the arriving wave packet is at a compatible frequency to the electron energy shell and causes interference, at incompatible frequencies it just passes through.

Not sure if this cuckooland or has been considered before? My physics level is not that high and has also been rusting for 20+ years.

Would be interested in hearing any thoughts, additions or criticisms.